# Changing axis label size in Python ggplot

Tags: python, python-ggplot

In R:

```
p + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 12))
```

How can you do this in the Python implementation?

---

> <sub>**Note**: I can't find a comprehensive source of documentation for *ggplot* in Python, which is making presumably simple requests like this very difficult.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
p + theme(axis_text = element_text(size = 12))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
p + theme(axis_title = element_text(size = 12))
```